# how to output pure text from PHP?

Tags: php, html, arduino, gsm

Basically I'm using a GSM module with arduino to make http request to my web server. And in turn the webpage returns tha output as : `#42.23#` .
On my GSM module I check for `#` and then I get to know that the next characters are my output.

But the server also sends some HTML tags as output to http request to my gsm module.
So is there any way to remove those HTML tags from my output so that the output contains only pure text of the above mentioned characters ?

I cannot use heavy code on my GSM module like parsing XML or JSON.

Comment: Without showing us some code, it'll be hard to help you

Comment: what kind of code ?? My PHP code or my Arduino code ?

Comment: what html is the server outputting?

Comment: It is giving some <DOCTYPE html and blah blah.

Comment: my guess is you are getting an error from the server, and it isn't php that is outputting it.. paste the html in your question

Comment: you using a CMS or framework? Perhaps your output's being wrapped for you. A simple `<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>` is not going to output anything except for hello world on its own.

Comment: well this is the web page that is the GSM module requesting `http://www.omerjerk.tk/karshin/getPrice.php`

Comment: thats google analytics code.. what is your host?

Comment: My host is 2freehosting.com 
And btw my PHP is only echoing the text. nothing else.

Comment: they are adding the tracking code to your page.. sorry, but it looks like you are out of luck as long as you are using their free service

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strip_tags()` in PHP to filter the returned string.  It will remove the HTML tags, but leave the text untouched.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't output HTML unless you tell it to.  The HTML is either coming from your PHP application because it is coded that way, or you are getting an error from the server, and the problem isn't with PHP.

You have google analytics code echoed.  Check your host configuration and your application code to see where it is coming from.

**Output from your page:**

```
#68.85#<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-5263515-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.3eeweb.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

**Edit**

2freehosting.com is adding the google tracking code.  You should use a paid host if you want to eliminate annoyances like this.